# AndroidManifest troubles...it won't play the splash screen first

Tags: android, android-intent

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="edu.virginia.cs2110.finalproject"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="14"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

       <activity
            android:name="edu.virginia.cs2110.finalproject.Splash"
            android:label="@string/splash_name"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <action android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

       <activity
            android:name="edu.virginia.cs2110.finalproject.InitialActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_set_difficulty"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name="edu.virginia.cs2110.finalproject.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape">
             <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="edu.virginia.cs2110.finalproject.MAINACTIVITY" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

No matter what I do to the second intent-filter (change the category from launcher and action from main) my emulator always ignores the first activity's launcher! I've looked online for over 3 hours and I cannot find an answer! Please help! Thank you!

Comment: remove second intent filter(from edu.virginia.cs2110.finalproject.InitialActivity ) and check whther you class package is same as edu.virginia.cs2110.finalproject.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the intent filter from 2nd and 3rd activity. You need only initialize it for the first time.

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="edu.virginia.cs2110.finalproject"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="14"
    android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

   <activity
        android:name="edu.virginia.cs2110.finalproject.Splash"
        android:label="@string/splash_name"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
            <action android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

   <activity
        android:name="edu.virginia.cs2110.finalproject.InitialActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_set_difficulty"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape">
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name="edu.virginia.cs2110.finalproject.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape">
    </activity>

</application>
```

Answer (score 0):

This.

```
<intent-filter>
   <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
   <action android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
</intent-filter>
```

Just could be in the first Activity than you can launch. The correct way is this.

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="edu.virginia.cs2110.finalproject"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="14"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

       <activity
            android:name="edu.virginia.cs2110.finalproject.Splash"
            android:label="@string/splash_name"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <action android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

       <activity
            android:name="edu.virginia.cs2110.finalproject.InitialActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_set_difficulty"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape">
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name="edu.virginia.cs2110.finalproject.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape">
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem is that you are adding

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
```

To all the activity tags but this filter should only be for the first activity to be launched.

Just remove the filter declaration from other two activities and add it to splash activity only so that android may know splash is first to be launched...